# How to change the default answer in QnA Maker?

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I need to change the default answer in the QnA Maker. I changed it in the configuration of the QnA App Service as seen here:

[image: default answer app config]

When I try it in the [QnA Maker Portal](https://www.qnamaker.ai/) I get the new default answer:

[image: portal default answer]

The problem is that when I try it in a channel like Microsoft Teams(or any other one), the default answer is not the new default answer:

[image: Micosoft Teams default answer]

My Microsoft Teams version is 1.2.00.27559 (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the default answer of a QnA Bot in a channel like Microsoft Teams, we have to change it in its source code. To access the source code, head to the Bot App Service and in the left hand blade look for the **App Service Editor** in the **Development Tools** tab:

[image]

Once there, we have to look for the **Dialog** folder and open up the **QnAMakerBaseDialog** file:

[image]

Now, we have to edit the **DefaultNoAnswer** const:

[image]

Then, we have to build the solution in the code editor. To do that, click the console icon on the left vertical menu, type "build.cmd" in the console and hit enter. This action should build and deploy your code.

[image]

If you have any issues building it this way, you can build it also from the App Service panel, going to Console, under the Development Tools tab(where the App Service Editor was)

[image]

Finally, the default answer should be displayed correctly. If not, restart the app service in the Azure portal and the new default answer should work fine!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The App Service Editor sourcecode is now in .js and no DefaultNoAnswer variable is available anymore. Even when you change the Stack settings to .NET

Answer (score 3):

One more way of changing your default answer to have it reflected it in different channels is to try through the Azure portal:

- Go to the Azure portal and navigate to the resource group where your QnA Maker service was created.
- Click on the specific App Service.

[image]

- Once the QnA MAker App Service opens up, click on the **Configuration** option under the Settings blade on the left pane.

  [image]
- Under Application settings, you will find the **DefaultAnswer** setting. Double click on the **DefaultAnswer** option and it will open up the **Add/Edit application setting** where you can change the value(your default answer) and click on **OK**.
  [image]
- Click on **Save** and then **Refresh** the app service.Now, try testing the default answer on any channel.
  [image]

Also, note that when you are making the changes in the qnamaker portal, make sure that you **save, train and publish the app** else the settings may not show the updated changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I've done to change the default answer before and it doesn't work in Teams. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: Are you using C# or node?

Comment: I'm using C# in the QnA service

Comment: Is your updated defaultAnswer showing up correctly on any other channel? What version of Teams are you using? Also, have you tried making changes to your code to change the defaultAnswer? You can refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/3727) GitHub issue which is similar to yours as it works for the user on webchat but not on Teams.

Comment: I tested it in the Web Chat channel and it is not working either. I haven't modified any code to make this QnA, just created the Azure needed resources, created the Knowledge Base and modified it. Where can I change the bot code?

Comment: My Microsoft Teams version is 1.2.00.27559 (64-bit)